# Special Characters displaying incorrectly on PHP version 7.4.27

Tags: php

When the site was running on PHP version 7.4.27 the polish characters were not displaying correctly as shown below

```
WspomóÅ¼ Misjonarzy Werbistów!enter code here
Twoja ofiara pomoÅ¼e naszym kapÅanom i braciom zakonnym gÅosiÄ EwangeliÄ w najdalszych zakÄtkach Åwiata.
```

But when downgraded the PHP version to 7.4.25 the polish characters were displaying as expected

```
Wspomóż Misjonarzy Werbistów!
Twoja ofiara pomoże naszym kapłanom i braciom zakonnym głosić Ewangelię w najdalszych zakątkach świata.
```

[Fixed bug #81518 (Header injection via default_mimetype / default_charset)](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.4.26)

A fixed bug that I found while reviewing over the changeLogs of PHP. Could this be a potential reason for the problem?

I would like to know what could be the possible cause of this issue in these different version of PHP and if there is any potential fix for this.

Comment: First check: Make sure your web server is using unicode to render all the contents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/283366)

Comment: _"Could this be a potential reason for the problem?"_ - unless you explicitly did anything like what is described here, https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81518 - very unlikely.

Comment: There are lots of unknowns from your question. For a start, I'd like to know what the request is (including headers!) and what the precise responses are (including headers, again!). Simple reason is that PHP doesn't display anything. Rather, it serves an HTTP request and leaves the displaying to the browser.

Comment: Everyone we tried all the solutions that you have mentioned and checked, all is encoded in UTF-8. The default charset of the site is set to UTTF-8 only.

I would like to mention specifically that the issue was resolved on changing the PHP version of the site. 

Please (@UlrichEckhardt) let me  know what specific information you would need from my end to further investigate this issue.